# Reading in Large SQL file in SQLite

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to read in a large SQL file (~ 0.5 GB) into SQLite. After I used .read "filename" , I got

```
Error: near line 25: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
Error: near line 52: near "LOCK": syntax error
```

The cursor blinks for a while and then the whole application shuts down. Am I reading in the file
correctly? How can I fix the errors if I can't open the files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file contains DDL SQL statements from a different SQL based database product.Please post the file contents (at least the commands at lines 25 and 52) if you want more help.